# Loading geojson file into codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm having trouble loading a geojson file from the api (gdelta project) into codename one.  The json comes in a file from this api that you have to download, however I haven't been able to find online or myself a way to download this file into my program. I've already tried putting it in Storage but I can't seem to be able to physically find where to put my file.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file to storage and give it any name you want but I'm guessing that what you are actually asking is how to connect to a webservice and parse the resulting JSON data. I don't have an immediate sample for geojson but I have samples for Googles geocoding webservices which should be pretty darn close. As a side note these samples are from the work I've been doing on the Uber clone application in the [online course](https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java)...

```
public static void findLocation(String name, SuccessCallback<Coord> location) {
    Rest.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json").
            queryParam("address", name).
            queryParam("key", Globals.GOOGLE_GEOCODING_KEY).
            getAsJsonMap(callbackMap -> {
                Map data = callbackMap.getResponseData();
                if(data != null) {
                    List results = (List)data.get("results");
                    if(results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                        Map firstResult = (Map)results.get(0);
                        Map geometryMap = (Map)firstResult.get("geometry");
                        Map locationMap = (Map)geometryMap.get("location");
                        double lat = Util.toDoubleValue(locationMap.get("lat"));
                        double lon = Util.toDoubleValue(locationMap.get("lng"));
                        location.onSucess(new Coord(lat, lon));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

The result is returned into the `Map` object which follows the hierarchy of the JSON data. You can place a breakpoint in the code and inspect the map value to see the result.